# Get key from dictionary by values and keys from nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have nested dictionary with this kind of structure:

```
 d = {
       "A":{
          "Param1":"7",
          "Param2":"5",      
       },
       "B":{
          "Param1":"1",
          "Param2":"2",      
       },
       "C":{
          "Param1":"X",
          "Param2":"Y",      
       },
       "D":{
          "SomeOtherParam1": "a",
          "SomeOtherParam2": "3",
       } 
    }
```

How to get dictionary key by nested key names and parameters? For example: Param1=1 and Param2=2 the output should be B. Is it even possible to do that?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @deceze here is exactly what I wanted to achieve:

```
pexist = next((k for k, v in d.items() if v.get('Param1') and v.get('Param2') if v['Param1'] == '1' and v['Param2'] == '2'), None)
    if pexist == None:
        print("Does not exist!")
    else:
        print(pexist)
```

Comment: `next(k for k, v in d.items() if v['Param1'] == '1' and v['Param2'] == '2')`…?

Comment: @deceze this works but I have exception KeyError if one of keys does not match. See my updated post. For example D key does not contain inside nested dictionary same keys as under A, B and C. The if I want to search by  SomeOtherParam1 and SomeOtherParam2 then I get exception because those dictionary keys does not exist in A, B, C I tried to surrounded by try...except block but still I can't get values

Comment: So `v.get('Param1')` then…

Answer (score 0):

A pandas module based solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {'Param1': '7', 'Param2': '5'}, 'B': {'Param1': '1', 'Param2': '2'}, 'C': {'Param1': 'X', 'Param2': 'Y'}})

s = (df.loc['Param1'] == '1') & (df.loc['Param2'] == '2')
print(*s[s].keys())
```

Output:

```
B
```

Comment: This is also fine but in my case I have to include name of keys of nested dictionary because some of nested dictionaries don't have same keys as others. See my updated post and D key.

Comment: this is also nice solution but actually I've took data from dataframe and put them in dictionary. My dictionary which I gave in example is result of dataframe.

Comment: @Josef You probably shouldn't do this cuz most of the problems can be solved quicker with dataframe. You didn't specified this in your question either.